# == Error == exception caught while parsing YAML file

Tags: python, yaml

I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with my yaml file. I copied the example over and filled in my samples in 10 different iterations to try and pinpoint the problem and I just can seem to make it work.

```
    orientation: "fr",
    type: "paired-end",
    right reads: [
      "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon1read1.fastq",
      "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon2read1.fastq",
      "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon3read1.fastq"

    ],
    left reads: [
      "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon1read2.fastq",
      "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon2read2.fastq",
      "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon3read2.fastq"

    ]
```

I get errors similar to these

```
== Error ==  exception caught while parsing YAML file (/wheeler/scratch/drob2727/matreads8.yaml):
while parsing a block mapping
  in "/wheeler/scratch/drob2727/matreads8.yaml", line 1, column 5
expected <block end>, but found ','
  in "/wheeler/scratch/drob2727/matreads8.yaml", line 16, column 6
```

I shortened my file to make it easier to manage but these are the types of errors that I get.

Comment: All valid JSON is also valid YAML. Consider writing your file in JSON if you want a simpler (and thus easier-to-reason-about) syntax; any compliant YAML parser will still load it.

Comment: "All valid JSON is also valid YAML"—IIRC that's only true of YAML 1.2, and there are a lot of older parsers around.

Answer (score 0):

Using a different parser I got

```
expected <block end>, but found ','
```

but in any case, the error is on `line 1, column 18` for me.  The error you provide does not match the data you pasted.

Removing the trailing `,` from your mapping parses fine for me:

```
orientation: "fr"
type: "paired-end"
right reads: [
  "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon1read1.fastq",
  "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon2read1.fastq",
  "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon3read1.fastq"

]
left reads: [
  "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon1read2.fastq",
  "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon2read2.fastq",
  "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon3read2.fastq"

]
```

Answer (score 0):

YAML doesn't use commas. Also there's specific syntax for dictionaries (hashmaps, or JSON objects) and lists (or arrays).

You can [find an overview here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html).
And a [good validator here](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator).

This worked for me:

```
orientation: "fr"
type: "paired-end"
right reads: 
  - "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon1read1.fastq"
  - "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon2read1.fastq"
  - "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon3read1.fastq"
left reads:
  - "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon1read2.fastq"
  - "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon2read2.fastq"
  - "/users/drob2727/supercomputer/Bon3read2.fastq"
```

Comment: I can see that its validated and I've tried iterations from the manual but I just can't seem to make it. I got this error with the code you provided me  main(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-nehalem/gcc-9.3.0/spades-3.14.1-u5nojwyz5gim2iz35tmi42qrycktdj5h/bin/metaspades.py", line 581, in main
    cfg, dataset_data, command_line = parse_args(args, log)
  File "/opt/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-nehalem/gcc-9.3.0/spades-3.14.1-u5nojwyz5gim2iz35tmi42qrycktdj5h/bin/metaspades.py", line 238, in parse_args

Comment: Well, the YAML error is gone so this is validating in your program. This answer worked. The other problem is separate and should be a separate question. If you create a new question, let me know, I'll try to help there too.